# How to enable multipleselection in qtreeview till ctrl key is pressed in pyqt5?

Tags: pyqt, qt4, pyqt4, qt5, pyqt5

I have a qtreeview, in which i want to enable mulitple row selection only when ctrl key is pressed . 
For multiple row selection i was using  setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)
But found out that it looks odd means if i simply clicked a item it get selected. I don't want that.  I want to select multiple rows selection only when ctrl is pressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ExtendedSelection rather than Multiselection.

```
tree.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
```